# Shell Scripting: execute echo statements with a time delay

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Is there any way I could run several echo statements one after the other with a delay?

For example:

The first statement will be:

```
echo Hello1
```

after 1/2 second, run the Second echo statement:

```
echo Hello2
```

Likewise, is it possible to run several statements one after the other with a time delay without printing all echoes at once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you would like to use `sleep <number of seconds>`
Like `sleep 60` to wait for a minute.

eg. run from commandline

$ `echo 'hello1'; sleep 2; echo 'hello2'`

or in a bash script file (myscript.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'hello1'
sleep 2
echo 'hello2 after 2 seconds'
sleep 2
echo 'hello3 after 2 seconds'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo Hello1
usleep 500000 # sleep 500,000 microseconds
echo Hello2
```

The `usleep(1)` command is part of the `initscripts` package on Fedora.

Answer (score 0):

for i in `echo "hello1 hello2 hello3"`; do echo $i; sleep 2; done

Comment: I don't know why the backtick (`) never shows, but in edit mode it's there. please assist.

Comment: The backtick is used to [mark inlince code] blocks(http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help). You need to escape the backtick witha peceding backslash: \\`

Comment: Thank Chris, that should be my complete comment awhile ago. Now, I stand corrected.  Again, thanks.